# C: error replacing gets() with fgets()

Tags: c, fgets

I am currently having an issue replacing gets() with fgets(). I have looked at multiple examples of doing this and it seems very straight forward however I am getting unexpected output in doing so. Using the gets() method in comments below, I get good behavior from my shell program I am writing, however when I change to the fgets() call, I get output ": no such file or directory" when giving input "ls". Like I said, with the gets() call it is working fine. code below:

```
int main(void) {

  while(1) {
    int i = 0;
    printf("$shell: ");

    scanf("%s", first);
    /* gets(input);*/
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

    //...parse input into tokens for exec system call...

    execvp(first, args);

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `gets`, `fgets` will read the newline and store it in the string.

From the man page:

> `fgets()` reads in at most one less than size characters from stream 
>   and   stores  them  into  the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops
>   after an   `EOF` or a newline.  **If a newline is read, it is stored into
>   the  buffer.**   A `'\0'` is stored after the last character in the
>   buffer.

You can remove the newline (if it is present) by replacing it will a null byte:

```
fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
if (input[strlen(input)-1] == '\n') input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Alternative way to remove the newline: `{ char *nl = strchr(input, '\n'); if (nl != NULL) *nl = '\0'; }`

Comment: `input[strlen(input)-1]` will read out of bounds if the empty string was read (this can happen if input stream is exhausted)